# How to read a String from console? NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, nosuchelementexception

I have to implement the interface *Terminal*, which has two methods. The first method is just a simple output and it works fine. The goal of the second method is to read the input from the user via console and return a splitted (whitespaces) array.

```
public class GameTerminal implements Terminal {

    @Override
    //output method

    @Override
    public String[] readInput() {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scn.nextLine();
        return input.trim().split("\\s+");
    }

}
```

This code throws a Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at student.GameTerminal.readInput(GameTerminal.java:20)
    ...
```

I tried to fix the problem with using *scn.next()*, *scn.hasNext()*, *scn.hasNextLine()* and a BufferedReader, but nothing works. I have no second *Scanner* and i don't use *scn.close()*.

The code runs with gradle in IntelliJ.

Has anabody a solution or idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think all you have to do is use the same Scanner between calls to preserve state:

```java
public class GameTerminal implements Terminal {
    private Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
    public String[] readInput() {
        String input = scn.nextLine();
        return input.trim().split("\\s+");
    }
}
```

A simple driver:

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GameTerminal terminal = new GameTerminal();
        String[] tokens = null;

        while ((tokens = terminal.readInput()) != null) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
        }
    }
}
```

Test run:

```sh
$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)/bin/java Example.java
some tokens
[some, tokens]
some more tokens
[some, more, tokens]
```